# How to retrieve a string value associated with a specific view?

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the `button`'s text/label programmatically. the `button`'s text/label is a `string` associated with a specific `id` of a specific view. I attempted to do so using the below posted code, but the `toast` displays `false`

javaCode:

```
protected String getBtnCurrentText() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String btnText = getResources().getString(R.id.fixNowBtnID);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), btnText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return btnText;
}
```

xml:

```
       <Button 
           android:id="@+id/fixNowBtnID"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:enabled="false"
           android:text="@string/fixNowBtnLabel"
           android:src="@drawable/gpsfix">
       </Button>
```

string_file:

```
<string name="fixNowBtnLabel">Fix Now</string>
```

Comment: simply do `btnName.getText()`.

Comment: I want to retrieve it from the resources (string.xml), is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve button text using `getText()` method as below

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fixNowBtnID);
String btnText = btn.getText();
```

instead as

```
String btnText = getResources().getString(R.id.fixNowBtnID);
```

**OR**

If you want to retrieve the text from `strings.xml` file then use pass string resource id `R.string.fixNowBtnLabel` instead of button id `R.id.fixNowBtnID` through `getString()` method

```
String btnText = getResources().getString(R.string.fixNowBtnLabel);
```

Comment: is there anyway to retrieve it from the resources the "string.xml" ?

Answer (score 0):

btnName.getText() is simply correct solution!